# i am not able to access kubernetes dashboard service through ingress domain ? it shows error 404 not found nginx?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, yaml

Both ingress kubernbetes-dashboard svc are in same namespace so how i can access from domain
dashboard is working properly when i https://: from this i am able to access kubernetes but i cant access it from host k8-test.com assignged in ingress-all.yaml file .. it gives an error **404 error found nginx**

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-all
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: k8-test.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-dashboard
                port:
                  number: 30329
```

this the yaml file for ingress
how i can solve this error????